# Get the file name of a instantiated class

Tags: php, class, abstract-class

Let's say I got the class name with `get_class($this)` within an abstract class method.

How can I also get the file name in which this class was defined? (full path)

I know I could pass it as an argument to my child class and create a property which is accessible in the parent class, but I was wondering if PHP has something built-in

Comment: You have the class name but no the full path right? And what you want to do is to get that full path of the child class through the php file that creates the instance of the child class (parent) right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the `ReflectionObject` class and its method, `ReflectionClass::getFileName`.

```
$reflection_class = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
echo $reflection_class->getFileName();
```

Check the function's manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php).